# How to pass \K to GNU on Windows grep?

Tags: cmd, grep

How can you pass `\K` to grep (from [Gnu On Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)) in the Windows CMD shell?

I want to [restore my display settings](https://wizardsoft.nl/products/wsdisplaysettings) when [a monitor is plugged in](https://superuser.com/a/885472/41259). The first step seems to be extracting the serial from EDID. To that end, running `dumpedid|grep -oP "(?<=Serial Number.{12}: )[0-9A-F]+"` works but `dumpedid|grep -oP "Serial Number.{12}: \K[0-9A-F]+"` comes back empty. I tried`echo "K"|grep -o "\K"` and it really seems it treats `\K` as a plain capital K. Adding a number of backslashes or `^` (because that's a Windows escape character) didn't make it work.

Comment: Single apostrophes do not work altogether, grep throws syntax errors.

Comment: yeah, I did mention changing them to double... so does the double quote version of my example work? and add sample lines from `dumpedid` output for us to test the grep command you are trying..

Comment: *Of course* PCRE is available since `(?<=)` works. And your example: echo 'foo=5, y=120' | grep -oP "(?<==)\d+" works, `echo 'foo=5, y=120' | grep -oP "=\K\d+"` is empty.

Comment: in that case may be the PCRE library it is using might not have `\K` implemented.. you'll have to dig which `grep` and PCRE versions are being used, etc... since `\d` works, I am assuming ``\`` doesn't need an extra escape..

Comment: OH! Of course, gow is known to be old, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164109/discussion-between-chx-and-sundeep).

Answer (score 1):

GOW at the writing of this is old and the PCRE used simply doesn't have `\K` yet: it's http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pcre.htm 7.0 while `\K` was added in 7.2.